# Cakephp loading Plugins installed with composer

Tags: cakephp-3.2

I installed friendsofcake/crud plugin with `composer require friendsofcake/crud`. composer installed it in vendor directory called `friendsofcake`.
Now i want to load the plugin into my app.doing something like this does work

```
cake plugin load friendsofcake
```

I get error `Exception: Plugin friendofcake/crud is could not be found> Is there something I should know about loading composer loaded plugins.

Comment: Please copy this plugin into the app/Plugin folder. Then try it.

Comment: I though cakephp plugin-installer took care of installing plugins to the correct directory. Also should I rename the plugin top directory.BTW  am using cakephp-3.2 So there is no app/Plugin

Comment: in cakephp 3, there is plugin folder in src folder . Are you tried with that.
Just copy your friendsofcake to src/plugin folder.

Comment: i tried that too doesn't work. i read cakephp [plugins](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html) installed plugins with composer sh'd work out of box

Comment: The plugin is called `crud` (respectively `Crud`), not `friendsofcake`!  So that load call is wrong. Also whenever receiving errors, please always post the complete, _exact_ error message including the full stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion)!

Comment: @ndm if I change it to `Crud` will it just work. and why did composer install  it in `vendor` when composer recognizes `crud` as cakephp-plugin type ?

Comment: how do you deal with plugin names prefixed with vendor name when installing with composer ?

Comment: Because that's where 3rd party/non-app specific plugins are ment to be stored. The plugin folder in your app is ment for 1st party plugins that are tied to your application. I would suggest that you have a look at the plugin docs: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html**, and in case using the proper name solved your problem, it would be better to close/delete the question, as it won't be of much help for future readers.